# What is the maximum allowance for group_concat_max_len in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, group-concat

I am using a group_concat to concatenate a lot of rows into one.

I set group concat to 10000 using:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 10000;
```

But even then, my output cells remain incomplete and end with ...

I tried setting group_concat_max_len = 20000 and even that didn't help.

I also tried setting group_concat_max_len to 99999999. It still doesn't complete my output text. And I checked one of the group concat stops at Length = 230 characters and then gives ...

Is there any other way?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len 18446744073709551615

Comment: @Mihai, why not post that as answer?

Comment: @Rahul I think because Bill Karwin posted it first ;) (+/- 60 seconds)

Comment: @Rahul Eh,just a quick google search,I`m more interested in learning something rather than break the point bank.

Comment: @Barranka, NO; Bill Karwin posted that much after Mihai's comment.

Comment: USe `SET SESSION  group_concat_max_len =..` before any query.

Comment: Yeah, I posted my answer about 1 minute after Mihai commented. If I had wanted to post just a link with no descriptive text, I probably would have been simultaneous. I don't care that much about the points either, but if questions are answered in comments alone, they always remain in the "unanswered" queue. People who don't post real answers are breaking StackOverflow's intended usage.

Comment: @Mihai, May be .. it's your personal view but if you post those comment as answer then a future reader may get helped. I am just thinking that.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Check out this link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

All the MySQL configuration variables are documented on that page, with details like minimum, maximum, default value, whether you can set them globally or per-session, whether you can change them on a running instance or does it require a restart, and other description of usage.

The maximum value for `group_concat_max_len` is 18446744073709551615.

The group-concat string does not end with "..."  If you try to group too much text, it just gets truncated. So I wonder if the problem is not with MySQL's settings, but with the display of your cells.

Comment: I set it to max now (18446744073709551615)

My string still gets cut off at the same place where it was earlier getting cut off. Hence, the change isn't getting effective clearly.

I closed my MySQL workbench and restarted it. But I am probably required to restart the MySQL instance.

Comment: Like I said, this is probably a limitation of the display, not the MySQL server.

Comment: So, when you say "I wonder if the problem is not with MySQL's settings, but with the display of your cells." --> You mean that the display could be truncated on the client side (MySQL Workbench in this case) ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. You can try a query like `select repeat('a', 1024*1024)` and see the "..." there too. It's an issue of MySQL Workbench showing only a limited prefix of the string, even though the server has sent back a long string.

Comment: Ok. I will try programatically running my query saving the results in a file and get back.

Comment: Yes. It worked programatically. So, the truncation was occuring on client side not on the server side.

Comment: if youre using workbench, you can right click the column and select `Open value in viewer' to see the whole string

Comment: @user3422637  How to change group_concat_max_len value?

Comment: I wonder if MySQL allocates that much bytes to that session upfront. How is memory managed for the parameter group_concat_max_len?

Answer (score 20):

For 32bit systems, the maximum value is 4294967295

For 64 bit systems, the maximum value is 18446744073709551615.

You can set the variable for your current session using

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=4294967295;
```

To set the variable forever use

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len=4294967295;
```

(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)