# How to count how many comma separated values in a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

In a query like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT( p.products_id )) AS comma_separated 
FROM   products p 
       left join specials s 
              ON p.products_id = s.products_id 
       left join products_to_categories p2c 
              ON p.products_id = p2c.products_id 
       left join products_description pd 
              ON p.products_id = pd.products_id 
       inner join products_attributes pa 
               ON p.products_id = pa.products_id 
WHERE  p.products_status = '1' 
       AND p2c.categories_id = 57 
       AND Date_sub(Curdate(), interval 7000 day) <= p.products_date_added 
ORDER  BY p.products_id DESC
```

I am getting a result of long list of comma separated numbers in a field named comma_separated.
How can I modify the query to count how many comma separated values there are?

**EDIT:**

Thanks, Barmar for the answer below.
I kept on getting a much shorter list of numbers (107 values instead of 4000+ in the actual count), and now I finally found the cause.
It seems GROUP_CONCAT is limited to 1024 characters, which is quite bad for my application.
Source: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2669-mysql-group-concat-fails-silently-when-it-hits-its-size-limit.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `COUNT` to count them.

```
SELECT Group_concat(DISTINCT( p.products_id )) AS comma_separated,
       COUNT(DISTINCT p.products_id) AS product_count
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I kept on getting 107 comma separated values while the count showed there should be more than 4,000. I just found the cause and updated my question with the details.

Comment: You can increase `GROUP_CONCAT_MAX_LEN`.

Comment: just found the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553823/what-is-the-maximum-allowance-for-group-concat-max-len-in-mysql