# Node.js util.promisify - Output stdout as obj or array instead of new lines

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm setting up a local script to setup a website locally and was trying to get some data from mysql.

```
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);

class Setup {
    constructor() {}

    async setLocalURLs(){
        const base_urls = await exec(`mysql -h${this.configFile.database.host} -u${this.configFile.database.username} -D ${this.databaseName} -p${this.configFile.database.password} -e 'SELECT id, value FROM table'`);
        console.warn(base_urls.stdout)
    }
}

module.exports = Setup;
```

It worked completely but I'm getting the results as new lines.
Results from my commandline data below:

```
2747    valueA 
2748    valueB
2749    valueC
2750    valueD
2751    valueE
```

Is it possible to output this as an obj or array instead of newlines within 'util'? (ofcourse without split on tab etc, I can do that myself ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback):

> - **`stdout`** `<string>` | `<Buffer>`

How you'd interpret this string is up to you. NodeJS couldn't miraculously know your intentions. That means that parsing this output and converting to objects and/or arrays is your job.

Comment: Found the solution for my question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql