# Indexing a MySQL table containing LONGTEXT field into Elastic Search

Tags: mysql, csv, elasticsearch

The table contains a `LONGTEXT` field that has special characters including quotes and commas.

How can I get this table into Elastic Search?

Exporting the table as CSV and then using Logstash could work. But the quotes and spaces cause extra columns to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

CSV isn't an ideal format for more complex data like that. You could try exporting to another structure like json ([example of how to export a table to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41760134/8443182)).

From there, you can insert the data using the [bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

Comment: Will having quotes in the text cause problems in JSON, too?

Comment: The documentation mentions that the special characters at escaped with backslashes. I would suggest giving it a try and inspecting the json.