# How to write mysql query to get JSON output?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json

I am exporting a part of MySQL Database as JSON Format.
I want to do this from mysql-cli without using any web interfaces like phpmyadmin or softwares like mysqlworkbench.

I am aware that I can do so by using php `json_encode()` function after a mysql query.

But are there any methods that can be used, so that I can write a mysql query to get the dump as JSON.

I used php to do this.

```
json_encode($result);
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: you can use `JSON_ARRAY` OR `JSON_OBJECT`

Comment: Go through these link might it helps you:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

From mysql version 5.7.8 you can use JSON_ARRAY, JSON_OBJECT to converting query output as json. Here is many more in mysql official documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html