# MySql get rows into single JSON object

Tags: mysql, json, object, mysql-5.5

I have table:

```
 -------+-------
| param | value |
|-------+-------|
|     A |  200.5|
|     B |   70.2|
 ---------------
```

When I execute:

```
select json_object(`param`, `value`) from `table`
```

I'm getting this:

```
{"A": "200.5"}
{"B": "70.2"}
```

But I want this:

```
{
 "A": "200.5",
 "B": "70.2"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [json aggregate function `json_objectagg()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-objectagg), available since MySQL 5.7:

```
select json_objectagg(param, value) js from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c198100c3e539f7bfc149ade18403abb)**:

```
| js                      |
| :---------------------- |
| {"A": 200.5, "B": 70.2} |
```

On earlier versions, where json aggregate functions are not available, you could do string concatenation:

```
select concat('{', group_concat('"', param, '": ', value separator ', '), '}') js
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=f3bdd0f78f2abe42eb52f680413549af)**

Comment: Thank you again GMB, but the server which I use is 5.5 ;-(

Comment: @iMarh: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wan't to get this result directly from the MySQL server, if that's the case, the closest to an answer comes this [How to convert result table to JSON array in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql).

If you're ok with getting the results further down the line you can always parse it using a language of your choice.

Hope that helps.