# how to get sql result as objects

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, group-by

I have three tables:

```
Table USER 
id
name
email
```

```
Table CAMPUS
id
user_id (foreign key)
name
```

```
Table POST
id
title
user_id (foreign key)
```

A User belongs to a Campus, and a Post belong to a User. I want to write a query to fetch posts inner join with user inner join with campus.

The result i get:

```
[{ 
id
username
campus name
title
... 
}]
```

Everything is in a single object. Instead, I want nested objects like this:

```
[{
post_title:
post_id:
...
User: {id name... }
campus:{id name ...}

}]
```

This way, User and Campus are inherited in the post according to foreign keys.
How can i achieve it with raw sql? Should I have to parse it later?

Comment: I think you want a json object. like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join and use json functions to generate the result that you expect.

Your question is not very accurate about the table structures, but this should look like:

```
select 
    json_object(
        'id',     p.id
        'title',  p.title
        'user',   json_object('id', u.id, 'name', u.name),
        'campus', json_object('id', c.id, 'name', c.name)
    ) post_object
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.user_id
inner join campus c on c.user_id = u.id
```

This gives you a resultset with a single column and one record per post as a json object that contains nested objects that represent the user and the campus.

If you want a result with a single row and all rows stuffed in a json array, you can use `json_arrayagg()` on top of this:

```
select json_arrayagg(
    json_object(
        'id',     p.id
        'title',  p.title
        'user',   json_object('id', u.id, 'name', u.name),
        'campus', json_object('id', c.id, 'name', c.name)
    ) 
) all_posts_objects
from posts p
inner join users u on u.id = p.user_id
inner join campus c on c.user_id = u.id
```

Comment: Thanks dude, i didn't know about json objects in sql before , i think this will work. Thanks again