# Query from a table to get a JSON result

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a table

[image]

I'd like to get the JSON result like this:

```
[
   {
      "Type":"I", //If group name is empty display ‘I’ otherwise, display ‘G’
      "StartDate":"20/12/2020 8:00am", //This is the start time 
      "Additional":{   //Because it is non-group (GroupName is null), so Additional is an object
         "Info":"having food"
      }
   },
   {
      "Type":"G",  //Group by Date and Group Name.
      "GroupName":"School", //If record has the same group name, 
      "StartDate":"20/12/2020 9:00am", //!!! Display the first entry’s start date  
      "Additional":[ // It is an array due to Group Name being a real value, the items in array is the record whose StartDate has the same Date value.
         {
            "StartDate":"20/12/2020 9:00am", //Display the start date 
            "Info":"Take bus"
         },
         {
            "StartDate":"20/12/2020 9:30am",", //Display the start date
            "Info":"On the beach"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Type":"G",
      "GroupName":"Class 1",
      "StartDate":"20/12/2020 11:00am",
      "Additional":[
         {
            "StartDate":"20/12/2020 11:00am",
            "Info":"Restaurant "
         },
         {
            "StartDate":"20/12/2020 13:00pm",
            "Info":"Walk on Lane"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Type":"I",
      "StartDate":"20/12/2020 15:00pm",
      "Additional":{
         "Info":"In museum"
      }
   }
]
```

Would any one help me on this? Thank you so much.

I also attach the JSON data in this picture so the JSON format would be clearer.

[image]

There is a typo sorry, this is the new picture:

[image]

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: For MySQL, you can see a simple way
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759147/2841508

Comment: @KashifSohail I'm using MSSQL Server.

Comment: Have you take a look at `FOR JSON` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: Which version of MSSQL to be precise you are using?

Comment: @KashifSohail The newest current one, could write the sql how I can get the above result? Thank you so much if you can help me.

Comment: Please, post test data as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft SQL Server documentation, `FOR JSON`, will work best for you. It is supported on SQL Server 2016 and above.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN GroupName is null THEN 'I'
           ELSE 'G'
       END as Type
       ,GroupName
       ,StartDate .....
FROM table
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi, I really need to complete this query. Can I add you as friend so I can ask you how to achieve it step by step?

Comment: I'm having the problem on grouping the items actually, because I can't figure it out using group by. I have no idea then.

Comment: sure, you can add

Answer (score 0):

When you form a JSON structure. Better to use with "INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES". So that it will have NULL for attribute If the value is missing.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2,... FROM Table FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```