# mySQL json result for functions

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following mySQL query that is working fine --

```
SELECT avg(age), avg(length)
FROM items
```

I need to produce the result in `JSON`. i tried the following along with some other queries with no success -- from [How to convert result table to JSON array in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql)

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('avg_age', avg(age), 'avg_l', avg(length)))  
FROM items
```

how can this be done?

TIA.

////////////////////

**UPDATE:** to get the result in `jdbc` later on --
add an alias to the result --

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('avg_age', avg(age), 'avg_l', avg(length))  as aa
FROM items
```

then

```
resultSet.getString("aa");
```

these on top of the accepted result

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`. `AVG()` is doing the aggregation already, you just need `JSON_OBJECT()` to put the results in JSON.

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('avg_age', avg(age), 'avg_l', avg(length))
FROM items
```

Comment: cool. not letting me accept yet-- will in 4mins.

Comment: how do you extract the result in jdbc? i'm looking for something like `resultSet.getString("json");`

got it -- deleting in a moment

Comment: No idea, I don't use JDBC.

Comment: Why don't you just produce JSON in the application program instead of the query?

Comment: why shd i - i dont need the json library elsewhere like that ,it'd also produce extra objects/burden