# How to dynamically provide key & values for JSON_OBJECT()?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching "FOR JSON PATH" (SQL Server) equivalent in MySQL and came across the following link -
[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql)

The most rated solution works perfectly but is it possible to provide the columns and values dynamically? I have over 20 columns and adding each key-value pair manually is hectic & not easy to maintain.

SQL Server Query-

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name,(
SELECT f.*
FROM files f
WHERE f.is_active = 1 AND f.user_id = u.user_id
FOR JSON PATH) as files
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id = 1
```

The output from the above query and the 1 generated using JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT())
function is the same.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name,
       (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('col1', col1, 'col2', col2, . . . ))
        FROM files f
        WHERE f.is_active = 1 AND f.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as files
FROM users u
WHERE u.user_id = 1;
```

That is, you can construct the object explicitly from the columns in `files` and then aggregate those values into an array.

Comment: instead of specifying the columns & values explicitly inside JSON_OBJECT, is it possible to select all the columns & values from the table directly similar to a "select * from files" query.

Answer (score 0):

For doing it explicitely typing the columns as per [your comment on @Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67968622/7291240), you need to execute a dynamic query ([PREPARED STATMENTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)).

```
set @qs = (SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(COLS)
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(
      '"', 
      `COLUMN_NAME`,
      '",',
      `COLUMN_NAME`
    ) as COLS
  FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
  WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'test'
  AND `TABLE_NAME`='Files'
) t);


set @fin = CONCAT("SELECT u.user_id, u.first_name,
       (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(",@qs,  "))
        FROM Files f
        WHERE f.is_active = 1 AND f.user_id = u.user_id
       ) as files
FROM Users u");

PREPARE dynamic_statement FROM @fin;
EXECUTE dynamic_statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE dynamic_statement;
```

[See example fiddle here.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rfLtsh4eicjwdgCF65tmBi/1)