# SQL how to create a JSON array from all the values in a single column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

this query below returns a single column from which I want to create a JSON array from:

```
SELECT CP.PageID 
FROM CommClient.dbo.ClientPage AS CP
INNER JOIN CommApp.dbo.Page as P ON CP.PageID = P.PageID 
INNER JOIN CommApp.dbo.PageGroup as PG ON P.PageGroupID = PG.PageGroupID
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ParentPageID FROM [CommApp].[dbo].[Page]
) AS PP 
ON P.PageID = PP.ParentPageID
WHERE ClientID = 102 AND P.ApplicationID = 4
ORDER BY P.pageID
```

[image]

The result I need is and array of values like this: [4000, 4010, 4110 ...]

I've tried to add FOR JSON PATH at the end of that query but I'm getting an array of object ([{"pageID":4000},{"pageID":4010},{"pageID":4110} ....) instead of an array of values and I'm at a loss, I'm a newb in SQL... Thanks!

Comment: Open https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758870/how-to-convert-result-table-to-json-array-in-mysql . I think it will help you.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Looks like SQL Server. Pls. tag it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function named GROUP_CONCAT in mySQL you can write as follows. Note the group by clause in the end and group_concat in select

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CP.PageID) as PageID
FROM CommClient.dbo.ClientPage AS CP
INNER JOIN CommApp.dbo.Page as P ON CP.PageID = P.PageID 
INNER JOIN CommApp.dbo.PageGroup as PG ON P.PageGroupID = PG.PageGroupID
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ParentPageID FROM [CommApp].[dbo].[Page]
) AS PP 
ON P.PageID = PP.ParentPageID
WHERE ClientID = 102 AND P.ApplicationID = 4
GROUP BY CP.PageID
ORDER BY P.pageID
```

Answer (score 0):

It varies in different DBMS.
SQL Server:

```sql
select '[' + string_agg(<expression>, ',') + ']'
-- the rest of your query
```

Postgres:

```sql
select json_agg(<expression>)
-- the rest of your query
```

Oracle:

```sql
select json_arrayagg(<expression>)
-- the rest of your query
```